# macOS flamenco worker test fails: blender_cmd […] does not exist

Tags: rendering, network

so I fire up the flamenco worker in test mode, it registers at the manager (yay!) and then I send a test job. Here's what comes next:

```
2020-04-04 15:52:23,700     INFO flamenco_worker.worker.FlamencoWorker.fetch_task Received task: 5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217
2020-04-04 15:52:23,700     INFO flamenco_worker.worker.FlamencoWorker Task changed status to active, pushing to manager
2020-04-04 15:52:23,700     INFO flamenco_worker.worker.FlamencoWorker Updating task 5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217 with status 'active' and activity Activity(activity='', current_command_idx=0, task_progress_percentage=0, command_progress_percentage=0, metrics={'timing': {}})
2020-04-04 15:52:23,720  WARNING flamenco_worker.commands.blender_render.(task_id=5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217, command_idx=0) Error in settings: blender_cmd 'Volumes/Applications/Blender' does not exist
2020-04-04 15:52:23,720     INFO flamenco_worker.worker.FlamencoWorker Task changed status to failed, pushing to manager
2020-04-04 15:52:23,721     INFO flamenco_worker.worker.FlamencoWorker Updating task 5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217 with status 'failed' and activity Activity(activity="blender_render.(task_id=5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217, command_idx=0): Invalid settings: blender_cmd 'Volumes/Applications/Blender' does not exist", current_command_idx=0, task_progress_percentage=0, command_progress_percentage=0, metrics={'timing': {}})
2020-04-04 15:52:23,722  WARNING flamenco_worker.runner.TaskRunner Command 0 of task 5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217 was not succesful, aborting task.
2020-04-04 15:52:23,722     INFO flamenco_worker.runner.TaskRunner Aggregated task timing info: {}
2020-04-04 15:52:23,722    ERROR flamenco_worker.worker.FlamencoWorker Task 5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217 failed
2020-04-04 15:52:23,722     INFO flamenco_worker.upstream_update_queue.TaskUpdateQueue Pushing task update to Manager, queue size is 2
2020-04-04 15:52:23,733     INFO flamenco_worker.upstream_update_queue.TaskUpdateQueue Pushing task update to Manager, queue size is 1
2020-04-04 15:52:38,726     INFO flamenco_worker.worker.FlamencoWorker Updating task 5e8890f55061d1b8b40f1217 with status '' and activity Activity(activity='', current_command_idx=0, task_progress_percentage=0, command_progress_percentage=0, metrics={'timing': {}})
2020-04-04 15:52:38,733     INFO flamenco_worker.upstream_update_queue.TaskUpdateQueue Pushing task update to Manager, queue size is 1
```

I think the important part is the first warning in line 4... I've read a couple of times that this path that "blender_cmd" wants to use tends not to work, but how can I change it (I've tried editing $PATH and .profile) and is that the issue at all?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to set the path to the blender binary of the workers in the setup of the manager! Switch the manager to setup mode, add the path to your blender binary (not the .app) and I set that binary to 'worker' only and added another one for 'user' only that points to the .app.